# Populating options for select using v-for VueJS after handling load data event

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have this *VueJS* application written using Typescript. I'm using *Axios* to get data from my database. This works well and the result I get is an array which is what I was expecting. When I do `console.log` on this array I can see that it's the correct result.

However, when I try to loop through this array to create the options for my select drop down I get a blank list. Why isn't the result coming up even though the variable I'm looping through is an array?

Edit: I've added a picture here showing the Axios result (`response.data`)

[image]

```
export default class EditRoute extends Vue {
  result: any;
  selectedRoute: string;
  constructor(){
     super();
     this.selectedRoute = "";
     this.result = [];
 }

  loadData() {
     axios.get('http://localhost:8080/routes')
     .then(response => (this.result = response.data));
  }
}
```

```
<select name="routeSelect" v-model="selectedRoute">
   <option v-for="routes in result" v-bind:key="routes.name" v-bind:value="routes.name"> {{ routes.name }} </option>
</select>
<button @click="loadData">Load data</button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your `result` is an object which is containing one item, that item is an array called `routes` in this case you should loop through `result.routes` like so :

```
 <option v-for="routes in result.routes" v-bind:key="routes.name" v-bind:value="routes.name"> {{ routes.name }} </option>
```

**Extra Example** :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      selectedUser: '',
      users: [],

    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    // this.loadData();
    //  this.timer = setInterval(this.loadData, 4000);
  },

  methods: {
    loadData: function() {
      axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(response => {
        this.users = response.data;

      }).catch(e => {

      })
    }
  }

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-axios@2.1.4/dist/vue-axios.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <select name="userSelect" v-model="selectedUser">
      <option v-for="user in users" v-bind:key="user.id" v-bind:value="user.name"> {{ user.name }} </option>
    </select>
    <button @click="loadData">Load data</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```